# Ruby &&= edge case

Tags: ruby

Bit of an edge case, but any idea why &&= would behave this way? I'm using 1.9.2.

```
obj = Object.new
obj.instance_eval {@bar &&= @bar} # => nil, expected
obj.instance_variables # => [], so obj has no @bar instance variable

obj.instance_eval {@bar = @bar && @bar} # ostensibly the same as @bar &&= @bar
obj.instance_variables # => [:@bar] # why would this version initialize @bar?
```

For comparison, ||= initializes the instance variable to nil, as I'd expect:

```
obj = Object.new
obj.instance_eval {@foo ||= @foo}
obj.instance_variables # => [:@foo], where @foo is set to nil
```

Thanks!

Comment: This post lovingly found with [SymbolHound](http://www.symbolhound.com/)!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is, because `@bar` evaluates to false, and thus the `&&=` would evaluate the expression no further... In contrast to your second expression, which assigns to `@bar` in any case, no matter what the following expression resolves to. The same goes with the `||=` case which evaluates the complete expression, no matter what initial value `@foo` resolved to.

So the difference between your first two expressions is, that in the first the assignment is dependent on the (undefined) value of `@bar` while in the second case you do an unconditional assignment. `&&=` is NOT a shortcut for `x = x && y`. It is a shortcut for `x = x && y if x`.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying!

Also, just got to the part of Programming Ruby 1.9 that explains this... probably should have look it up :/

Comment: @Alan feel free to accept my response as answer if it solves your question.

Comment: @AlanO'Donnell [this article offers a detailed explanation](http://www.rubyinside.com/what-rubys-double-pipe-or-equals-really-does-5488.html) of the topic.

Comment: It is indeed a shortcut for x = x && y

Comment: @blj No... It's more like `x && x = y`... Your suggestion does something different in Ruby.