# In ruby &&= operator is flaky?

Tags: ruby

Encountered a weird behavior in Ruby. Wonder if it's just me. I am on ruby 2.3.3. And here's the log. Operate them in order, you should be able to reproduce it.

```
[1] pry(main)> a &&= nil.a
=> nil
[2] pry(main)> a &&= 1.to_s
=> nil
[3] pry(main)> a = 1 && 1.to_s
=> "1"
[4] pry(main)> a &&= 1.to_s
=> "1"
[5] pry(main)> a &&= nil.a
NoMethodError: undefined method `a' for nil:NilClass
from (pry):5:in `__pry__'
```

Look at [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2983028/4164651) and [5], as well as [2](http://www.rubyinside.com/what-rubys-double-pipe-or-equals-really-does-5488.html) and [4]

**Edit:**

There is a [similar question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2983028/4164651). And a [blog post](http://www.rubyinside.com/what-rubys-double-pipe-or-equals-really-does-5488.html) that tries to explain it. But I don't think they explain it.

In the [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2983028/4164651), it says `&&=` is a shortcut for `x = x && y if x`. But consider this:

```
num = 1
a &&= num.to_s
# => nil
```

vs

```
num = 1
a = num && num.to_s if num
# => "1"
```

And in ruby if `a` is undefined, `a = a` gives you `nil`. `x = x && y if x` by itself is a strange operation.

```
x = x && y if x
```

This should be the same as below

```
if x
  x = x && y
end
```

But this throws an error because `x` is not defined. So which part is actually evaluated first? Is it `x = x && y` or `if x`?

Comment: What do you think is wrong with that? It seems perfectly fine to me.

Comment: `a &&= nil.a` should always be `nil` instead of raising error sometimes. `a &&= 1.to_s` should always assign `'1'` to `a` instead of `nil` sometimes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ruby &&= edge case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2982947/ruby-edge-case)

Comment: Particularly, `&&=` is NOT a shortcut for `x = x && y`. It is a shortcut for `x = x && y if x`. The `if x` is causing your confusion, I think...

Comment: They said `x = x && y if x`, so your `a = num && num.to_s if num` is wrong and should be `a = a && num.to_s if a`.

Comment: And where's the evidence for "by most people's standard"? You're not most people.

Comment: @StefanPochmann you made a point there. but this is not the equivalent of what the style guide suggests. `a &&= b.c` != `a = b && b.c` And it seems that's how most people are understanding it.

Comment: So far in 2017, 243 SO questions concerned apparent Ruby bugs. Two of those identified actual bugs.  (Disclaimer: my estimates.)

Comment: @StefanPochmann The style guide suggests using it to replace ‘a = b && b.some_method’. But they have different intended purpose. If you **read** the style guide you will see that. And **imho** that’s miss leading and can cause unintended bug.

Comment: @CarySwoveland this is not a bug you’re right. But it’s one of those **uh what?** operations that throw some people off. And apparently not many people understand what ‘&&=‘ actually does and hence the blog post and the other SO thread. And now this thread is going to give people a better understanding of what it does (at least to me).

Comment: You began with "Encountered a weird bug.", not "Encountered a Ruby behavior I don't understand".  Other than that, it's a good question. My comment was in jest (refecting my observations over time) and not directed at your question specifically.

Comment: @StefanPochmann https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide/blob/master/README.md#self-assignment

Comment: @CarySwoveland good point. I thought it was a bug. But now I changed my mind. I’ll fix that

Comment: @StefanPochmann https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide/blob/master/README.md#double-amper-preprocess

Comment: @EdmundLee Those don't show what you claim.

Comment: @EdmundLee Presumably you mean the guide's `something = something && something.downcase` vs `something &&= something.downcase`. Which is **not** `something = somethingELSE && somethingELSE.downcase` vs `something &&= somethingELSE.downcase`. You messed that up just like you messed up when you took `x = x && y if x` and incorrectly turned it into `a = num && num.to_s if num` instead of `a = a && num.to_s if a` like I told you earlier and which you still didn't fix. You can't just use different things where the rules are about same things.

Comment: @EdmundLee If you saw the rule *"If person X kills someone then person X must go to prison"*, do you honestly think it's ok to interpret that as *"If person X kills someone then person Y must go to prison"*? Really?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's worth noting a few things, several mentioned by Stefan below, about the properties of `&&=`:

- The variable on the left hand side is always considered *defined* whether or not an assignment is actually made.
- A defined variable assumes the value of `nil` if no value has been explicitly assigned.
- The term on the right hand side is only evaluated if `a` is logically true, or more specifically, if `a` is not one of `nil` or `false`.
- As such, if `a` is not logically true, then the right hand side only has to be *syntactically valid*, as it won't get evaluated. That means broken code like `nil.a` is acceptable under those specific conditions, it will get parsed but is otherwise ignored.
- If `a` is `nil` or `false` then the value of `a` is not changed.

A long-form version of `a &&= b` is actually:

```
a = if (a)
  b
else
  a
end
```

Where `b` can be any expression, including things like `a &&= b &&= c`

As to your example, this is to do with if the right hand side of the expression gets evaluated or not. In the first case `a` is undefined, so it won't be.

Later on when you actually define `a` as something then it must execute the right hand side, so you end up evaluating `nil.a` and it explodes.

You can do anything you want in this case:

```
nil && whatever(this!, will!, not!, ever!, run!)
```

It's not flaky, it's just not behaving like you think it is. `&&` is one of those things that's *short-circuit* evaluated. That is in:

```
a && b && c && d
```

The actual interpretation is:

```
if a
  if b
    if c
      d
    end
  end
end
```

So in this representation it's obvious that if any of those conditions fail it bails out and skips the rest.

One thing to observe is that `a` pops into existence using `&&=` automatically:

```
local_variables
# => [:_]
a &&= true
# => nil
local_variables
# => [:a,:_]
```

This is not true with `&&`.

Comment: In your last block of code, only if `a`, `b` or `c` is defined. Otherwise, it throws an error before it gets to the next nested block.

Comment: That's because this isn't using the `&&=` operator which has the side-effect of defining the thing on the left side of it. It doesn't necessarily *populate* that variable, though. You can see this in action by calling `local_variables` before and after you run `a &&= nil`

Comment: And what confused me was, before `a` was defined, `a &&= 1` doesn't explode. But it seems it should according to your explanation (since `a` should be evaluated first)?

Comment: The left hand side is *conditionally* evaluated depending on the value of `a`, but `a` is implicitly created as a variable even if that variable is never assigned a value. Sometimes Ruby will "variableify" things if it deems that necessary, like the degenerate case of `a = a` which "works".

Comment: @StefanPochmann that's a good point, I'll edit it. Got mired in a C++ debate on another question and lost track here.

Comment: @StefanPochmann I think that got it, where now it stays as *whatever* if the first `if` doesn't pass. This is surprisingly hard to get right!

Comment: @StefanPochmann Thanks for the feedback here. I've moved a more complete summary up to the top of the answer with credit.

Comment: I am going to make this conclusion. **Don't use `&&=`**

Comment: @EdmundLee Yeah, it's rare to see that in production code as it means "define if only already defined". I see `||=` all the time, though.

Comment: @tadman it's actually recommended in ruby style guide. Created a PR and hopefully it got merged. I will post the link to my edit.

Comment: @tadman Actually, your "long-form version" is still not equivalent. Well, maybe it is if `a` really literally is just `a`. But not if it's for example `h[0]`: https://ideone.com/q8uuJg Your version creates the entry while `&&=` doesn't.

Comment: @HolgerJust Yeah, it wasn't written very well. I took the liberty now to put the context first and to add an "only" (that lack had been bugging me already).

Comment: @tadman Hope that edit is ok. I btw cleaned up (i.e., removed) my obsolete comments.